# SQL Server 2008 - how to automatically drop and create and output table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert

I would like to set up a table within a SQL Server DB that stores the results from a long and complex query that takes almost an hour to run. After running the query the rest of the analysis is done by colleagues using Excel pivot tables.

I would prefer not to output the results to text, and want to keep it within SQL Server and then just set up Excel to pivot directly from the server.

My problem is that the output will not always have exactly the same columns, and manually setting up an output table to INSERT INTO every time would be tedious.

Is there a way to create a table on the fly based on the type of data you are selecting?

E.g. if I want to run:

```
SELECT 
  someInt, 
  someVarchar, 
  someDate 
FROM someTable
```

And insert this into a table called OutputTable, which has to look like this

```
CREATE TABLE OutputTable
(
  someInt int null
  someVarchar varchar(255) null,
  someDate date null,
) ON [primary]
```

Is there some way to make SQL Server interrogate the fields in the select statement and then automatically generate the CREATE TABLE script?

Thanks
Karl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  someInt, 
  someVarchar, 
  someDate 
INTO dbo.OutputTable
FROM someTable
```

...doesn't explicitly generate a CREATE script (at least not one you can see) but does the job!

Comment: You,he can use `SELECT ... INTO ..`, but unless he creates some sofisticated way to clean up these "pseudo-temp" tables, the database would grow quite large (I'm just assuming that anything that "stores the results from a long and complex query that takes almost an hour to run" uses also lots of space, correct me if I'm wrong) and not only he can run out of space but constant DB resizing would also severely hurt performance.

Comment: For this specific example, I don't think there needs be a sophisticated way to clean up the table.  Such a query looks like it'd be scheduled - in which case a two step agent job that first drops the table (if it exists) and then runs the query would be fine.  I don't think the idea here is that these are pseudo temp tables - not if they're to be used to pivot in Excel.  Running out of space etc. is a DBA issue - and I can only assume that the database is configured properly.